# If a database table is expected to grow more columns later, then is it good design to keep those columns as rows of another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have a database for a device and the columns are like this:

```
DeviceID | DeviceParameter1 | DeviceParameter2
```

At this stage I need only these parameters, but maybe a few months down the line, I may need a few more devices which have more parameters, so I'll have to add `DeviceParameter3` etc as columns.

A friend suggested that I keep the parameters as rows in another table (ParamCol) like this:

```
Column           | ColumnNumber 
---------------------------------
DeviceParameter1 | 1  
DeviceParameter2 | 2  
DeviceParameter3 | 3
```

and then refer to the columns like this:

```
DeviceID | ColumnNumber <- this is from the ParamCol table   
---------------------------------------------------
switchA  |   1  
switchA  |   2  
routerB  |   1  
routerB  |   2  
routerC  |   3
```

He says that for 3NF, when we expect a table whose columns may increase dynamically, it's better to keep the columns as rows. I don't believe him.

In your opinion, is this really the best way to handle a situation where the columns may increase or is there a better way to design a database for such a situation?

Comment: "I don't believe him."..  yeah don't believe him. Unless you're expecting columns added constantly or in the thousands (in which case you should reconsider what those data points are relationally; they're probably some other 1 to many table).

Comment: I agree that having to provide a default value to the columns could be a problem. But does 3NF really talk about such a design where columns are added as rows? Would it have been better design to create separate tables for every individual device, rather than have a generic table to store all devices (which is why the problem of adding columns came up)

Comment: How dissimilar are the devices and the parameters they require?  Note that the "rows" solution tends towards an [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model), which is good for highly dynamic solutions, but has its own problems.  If most of the attributes are the same, and are mostly filled, I'd stick with just adding columns over time.  If everything is different, adding rows/keys will make things easier, but then you need to reconstruct the parameter lists (MySQL seems to make that easy, given other questions on the site).

Comment: Thanks for the link to EAV. It's exactly what I needed, to know the disadvantages of the approach. Your comment should have been an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a "generic data model" question - if you google the term you'll find quite a bit of material on the net.

Here is my view: if and only if the parameters are NOT qualitatively different from the application perspective, then go with the dynamic row solution (i.e. a generic data model). What does qualitatively mean - it means that within your application you don't treat Parameter3 any different to Parameter17.

You should never ever generate new columns on-the-fly, that's a very bad idea. If the columns are qualitatively different and you want to be able to cater for new ones, then you could have  a different Device Parameter table for each different category of parameters. The idea is to avoid dynamic SQL as much as possible as it brings a set of its own problems.

Answer (score 1):

Adding dynamic column is a bad idea, Actually it's a bad design. I would agree with your second option , Adding rows is OK,

Because if you want to add dynamically grow the columns then you have to provide them a default value, also you will not be able to use them as 'UNIQUE' vals, you will find really hard while updating the tables, So better to stick with adding 'ROWS' plan.